# Bash script failure

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have this script. It works fine on one of system but it's giving some error on another machine:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 EXEC_DIR=`dirname ${0}`
  3 source ${EXEC_DIR}/config.sh
  4
  5 last_exec_date=$(cat $EXEC_DIR/$collector_temp | tail -1)
  6
  7 if [ -f $EXEC_DIR/$collector_temp ]; then
  8     last_exec_date=$(cat $EXEC_DIR/$collector_temp | tail -1)
  9 else
 10     date +%s >> ${EXEC_DIR}/$collector_temp
 11     last_exec_date=$(cat $EXEC_DIR/$collector_temp | tail -1)
 12 fi
 13
 14
 15 ssh $dns_ssh bash -c "'
 16 count=1
 17 any_query_file=${query_file_path}${query_file}*
 18 last_exec_date=${last_exec_date}
 19 qfiles_dns=${qfiles_dns}
 20 today="'$(date +%Y%m%d)'"
 21
 22 for a in "'$any_query_file'"; do
 23     if test -f "'$a'"; then
 24         :
 25     else
 26         echo "No queries.log.* files found iin $query_file_path"
 27         exit 31
 28     fi
 29 done
 30
 31 for b in "'$any_query_file'"; do
 32     time_stamp="'$(stat -c "%Z" $b)'"
 33     if [[ "'$time_stamp'" -ge "'$last_exec_date'" ]]; then
 34         file_rename="'$(printf  "%s""%s""_%03d" '${query_file}' "$today" "$count"  )'"
 35         awk "'"{ if (NR % 10 == 0) print }"'" "'$b'" > "'$qfiles_dns/$file_rename'"
 36         let count=count+1
 37     fi
 38 done
 39
 40 if [[ "'$count'" = "'1'" ]]; then
 41     echo "'No new "'$query_file'" files found on "'$dns_ssh'" '"
 42     exit 32
 43 fi
 44 '"
 45
 46 #### SUMIT
 47
 48 exit 12
 49
 50 #### SUMIT
 51
```

Its giving me this error:

Unmatched '.

count=1: Command not found.

any_query_file=queries.log.*: No match.

last_exec_date=1419574736: Command not found.

qfiles_dns=: Command not found.

Illegal variable name.

any_query_file: Undefined variable.

a: Undefined variable.

else: endif not found.

Some values in the variables are obtained from another script.
What could be the error ? It is running fine on another machine.

Comment: What are the values of some of the variables.  Like `dns_ssh` `collector_temp` etc?

Comment: Feel free to take a look at [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

> else: endif not found.

This and the others are all `csh` error messages. Somehow you're invoking `csh` on that host instead of `bash`. You'll have to check the remote system to find out exactly why that's happening. Someone may have set up an alias to invoke csh instead of bash, or they may have replaced the bash executable program, or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks Kenster for your hint. That seems to be the problem but I a not able to verify it. 
'You'll have to check the remote system to find out exactly why that's happening. Someone may have set up an alias to invoke csh instead of bash'

How do I check that ???